# sed to remove the third occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: bash, sed

The input file looks like this:

```
Jan 23 14:57:16 TCP 217.79.188.21:80 in
```

I tried:

```
sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/'
```

But it keeps removing :16 instead of removing the :80

How can I fix this?

Comment: If it's `:80` occurance everytime, just use `:80 in` for sed condition

Comment: For me it just works: $ echo "Jan 23 14:57:16 TCP 217.79.188.21:80 in" | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/' results in
Jan 23 14:57:16 TCP 217.79.188.21 in

Comment: works also for me, formula is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo "Jan 23 14:57:16 TCP 217.79.188.21:80 in" | sed 's/:..//3'
Jan 23 14:57:16 TCP 217.79.188.21 in
```

or (more likely as port number may be any number):

```
echo "Jan 23 14:57:16 TCP 217.79.188.21:80 in" | sed 's/:[^ ]*//2'
Jan 23 14:57:16 TCP 217.79.188.21 in
```

Answer (score 0):

Try matching both the IP and the port, and replacing it with the just the IP.

Comment: I had a typo in my awk statement. Sorry guys, user error. Thanks for the replies anyway.

Comment: please edit your question to indicate that this thread is resolved, otherwise people have to read thru all of the messages to find out there is nothing to help with. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E -e 's/:[[:digit:]]{1,3} in/ in/'
```